# Regex not allowing certain special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex which does not allow certain special characters:

```
if (testString.match(/[`~,.<>;':"\/\[\]\|{}()-=_+]/)){    
    alert("password not valid");
}
else
{
    alert("password valid");
}
```

This is working. This regex will accept a password if it does not contain any of the special characters inside the bracket `(~,.<>;':"\/\[\]\|{}()-=_+)`.

My problem here is it also don't allow me to input numbers which is weird.

Anything I missed here? Thanks in advance!

Here is a sample:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCn7h/2/)

Comment: while you can use @m.buettner s answer to fix your regex, you're still doing it wrong: use a whilelist aproach, specifying the *valid* characters instead!

Comment: @DarenThomas totally agree

Comment: I also have the if condition to check the valid characters only but I used it on the server side. What i'm doing right now is creating a client side function that will check if some of the not allowed characters are present, change the password indicator signal to weak.

Comment: Also on the client side, I have a js function to check if valid special characters are present, change the password indicator signal to strong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got a character range in there: `)-=` which includes all ASCII characters between `)` and `=` (including numbers). Move the `-` to the end of the class or escape it:

```
/[`~,.<>;':"\/\[\]\|{}()=_+-]/
```

Also, you don't need to escape all of those characters:

```
/[`~,.<>;':"/[\]|{}()=_+-]/
```

Note that in your case, it is probably enough for you, to use `test` instead of `match`:

```
if (/[`~,.<>;':"/[\]|{}()=_+-]/.test(testString))){
    ...
```

`test` returns a boolean (which is all you need), while `match` returns an array with all capturing groups (which you are discarding anyway).

Note that, as Daren Thomas points out in a comment, you should rather decide which characters you want to *allow*. Because the current approach doesn't take care of all sorts of weird Unicode characters, while complaining about some fairly standard ones like `_`. To create a whitelist, you can simply invert both the character class and the condition:

```
if (!/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(testString)) {
   ...
```

And include all the characters you do want to allow.

Comment: Thank you for this! Also for the `test` thing.