# How to don't allow special character only in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't want to allow special characters, characters should only be accepted.

```
<input type="text" id="user" onClick="insert()">

function insert() {
   var user = $("#user").val();
   var re = /^[@#%&*()_|$:;-+]+$/;
   if(user.search(re) == 1) {
      alert("ERROR");
   } else {
      alert("OK");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#theIdofInput').bind('keypress blur', function() {

  $(this).val(
             $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9.]/g,'')
             )

});
```

You may add any exception in the `replace` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You Should thy this:

```
/[`~,.<>;':"\/\[\]\|{}()=_+-]/
```

or this

```
/[`~,.<>;':"/[\]|{}()=_+-]/
```

[Regex not allowing certain special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398025/regex-not-allowing-certain-special-characters)