# Regular expression for text box validation with alphabets, numbers and some special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a text box using regular expression. I want to add alphabets, numbers and some special characters like "& - / . # , space".
I have tried with this 
 `/^[a-zA-Z0-9&-/.#,\s]*$/`. 
 It is working fine except the *. I want to prevent * symbol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398025/regex-not-allowing-certain-special-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the hyphen and slash:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9&\-\/.#,\s]*$/
```

`&-/` is interpreted as a range, just like `a-z`, which include `*` and some other characters.
Escaping the slash is not mandatory here, but I always try to escape it in regex literals (`/this syntax/`).

Answer (score 1):

Put & at the end of regex Like below

> /^[a-zA-Z0-9-/.#,\s&]*$/